# Problem with an entity using just a list of values in Spring Data JDBC

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jdbc

I'm using Spring-Boot 2.5.0, Java 11, a Postgres DB and Lombok. I have e.g. a list of articles as an entity:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Articles {

    @Id
    private Long id;


    @Builder.Default
    private List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and the *Article* value:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Article {
    private String name;
    private Integer price;
}
```

and the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ArticlesRepository extends CrudRepository<Articles, Long> {
}
```

The db schema looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "articles" (
  "id"                  BIGSERIAL  NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE "article" (
  "name"               VARCHAR(255),
  "price"              INTEGER,
  "articles"           BIGINT,
  "articles_key"       INTEGER
);
```

And testing it:

```
var article1 = Article.builder().name("T-Shirt").price(1635).build();
var article2 = Article.builder().name("Shoes").price(5670).build();
var articles = Articles.builder().articles(List.of(article1, article2)).build();
articlesRepository.save(articles);
```

will cause an exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO "articles" VALUES ()]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
```

If I just add a field to *Articles* like e.g. *name* in this case, it works fine:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Articles {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Builder.Default
    private List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: Since `id` is autogenerated, it's left out of the insert statement. As your table doesn't contain anything else, the result is a syntactically incorrect insert statement. But if `Articles` doesn't contain anything besides an `id`, what's the purpose of the entity?

Comment: You're right from the db point of view. But just creating a dummy field, which is not needed on the Java side looks weird. The purpose of the entity with just an id is to have a back reference id for the article table

Comment: You're going to have to explain the purpose better. How is it useful? What does it allow you to do? You can now get a `List<Article>` based on `id`, but you can do that with a `WHERE` clause without adding an unnecessary table.

Comment: @Kayaman It's not an unneccessary table,  it's how Spring Data JDBC [see Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#jdbc.entity-persistence.types) works. In this case I don't have to create any db query on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a current limitation of Spring Data JDBC with some databases.

Some databases require an insert to have at least one column.

As a workaround you could either add a dummy column that you don't actually use. Alternatively you could not autogenerate the id.

Please consider [creating an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc) so that this gets eventually fixed.

Comment: Thanks Jens! Actually I have an extra column in my app, so its no big deal. I just noticed that behavior and want to make sure that I'm not missing anything. I'll create an issue.